# Acessing ReportService in ReportServer From Windows Application

Tags: windows, reporting-services

Here i have a windowsapplication and a SSRS Report where report is implemented in Report server,and herei try to call that report from a windows application.In my button click i add this code:

```
string reportName = "Crime_Traking_Report";
            reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials =new ReportServerCredentials("isroScientist", "password12345678", "Nasa");
            reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
            try
            {
                reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://13.88.91.156/ReportServer");
            }
            catch (UriFormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bad Url format");
            }
            reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/iSROReportsStandard/" + reportName;
            reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
            reportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Here definitely i want to pass the credentials to access ,but when i run my application its giving an error like this "ReportServerCredentials has no constructor Defined", what change i want to make in order to pass the credentials successfully through my code.please explain me through code.

Answer (score 1):

The question is has the same solution as your other qustion [Error while accessing report service(remote mode) from Report server with in a windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409018/error-while-accessing-report-serviceremote-mode-from-report-server-with-in-a-w). See my answer there. The `ServerReport.SetDataSourceCredentials` Method should be used.