# Error while accessing report service(remote mode) from Report server with in a windows application

Tags: windows, reporting-services

I got following error while accessing report from report server . I am using a windows application to access my report.This is my code:

```
private void rptviewer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string reportName = "Crime_Traking_Report";
            string reporturl = @"http://13.800.91.136/ReportServer";
            string reportpath = @"/iSROReportsRK7/";
            reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
         reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportServerCredentials("isro", "password1209083$", "Rocket");


            try
            {
                reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(reporturl);
            }
            catch (UriFormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bad Url format");
            }
            reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = reportpath + reportName;
            reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
            reportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();

        }


        public  class ReportServerCredentials : IReportServerCredentials
        {
            private string _UserName;
            private string _PassWord;
            private string _DomainName;

            public ReportServerCredentials(string UserName, string PassWord, string DomainName)
            {
                _UserName = UserName;
                _PassWord = PassWord;
                _DomainName = DomainName;
            }




            public System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
            {
                get { return null; }
            }

            public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
            {
                get { return new NetworkCredential(_UserName, _PassWord, _DomainName); }
            }
            public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, out string user,out string password, out string authority)
            {
                authCookie = null;
                user = password = authority = null;
                return false;
            }

        }
```

Error i got is :Error   1   Property or indexer 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
Error   2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'Daily_Crime_Traking.Form1.ReportServerCredentials' to 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportServerCredentials'

I tried by changing the class name to CustomServerCRedintials inorder to avoid a nameConflict issue then also the same kind of Error what i want to do to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to set credentials

```
reportViewer1.ServerReport.SetDataSourceCredentials({ new DataSourceCredentials {
    Name = _DataSourceName,
    UserId =_UserName,
    Password = _PassWord
} })
```

see: [ServerReport.SetDataSourceCredentials Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd475336.aspx)

[DataSourceCredentials Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.datasourcecredentials_members.aspx)
[Reporting Services Report Viewer using SQL Authentication](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/stevewright/archive/2006/09/14/Reporting-Services-Report-Viewer-using-SQL-Authentication.aspx)

Comment: Here i dont have any dataset,am using remote method,not local method.its not working..

Comment: Name is the name of DataSource to set credential for. Is there a datasource in your report?